# sharepoint resource and workforce management tools

Tags: 2013, 2010

Are there any tools available for capacity management for resources including manpower and Infra based on sharepoint?

Likely need to capture skill sets of manpower and check the list of available resources etc..

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Project pro for Office 365](https://products.office.com/en-us/project/project-online-with-project-pro-for-office-365). This is a sharepoint port over of Project 2013. Its also available as a standalone install for sharepoint servers. It is a great tool for managing human resource, project timesheets etc. Also it happens to have good integration with SharePoint and Project Professional.

You can download the quickstart guide [here](https://support.office.com/en-NZ/Article/Project-2013-Quick-Start-Guide-1c7a29f9-c0a1-486d-b945-c48cb0091ddb)